# Recursive function postgres to get the latest ID

Tags: postgresql, function, recursion, triggers, coalesce

I want to use a function in PostgreSQL to get the latest ID related to a history:

```
CREATE TABLE "tbl_ids" (
 "ID" oid,
 "Name" text,
 "newID" oid
);
```

After creating this simple table, I have no idea where to start my function, and before you ask: I know about COALESCE()-function, but I'm going to have more then one parent-ID in the future.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_lastes_id(ID oid, newID oid) RETURNS oid AS $$
 BEGIN
  IF new IS NOT NULL THEN
   --USE old--      
  END
  IF new IS NULL THEN
   get_latest_id(new, "newID")
  END
END;
```

I gotta say it because you'd find out anyway: I'm really new in functions with PostgreSQL and I'm not even sure if this is possible. But assuming COALESCE()-Function also exists it has to be a server-side function I guess.

Comment: You shouldn't be using oids in the first place. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not clear what you are asking.  oid's are probably not the best type to use primarily because they are an internal type designed for the system libraries and therefore you cannot guarantee they will act the way you expect.

Secondly this seems to me to be a poor choice tools if you want to use recursion to just get the latest.   If you want things to perform well, try to think in set operations rather than imparitive algorithms.

If you want a trigger to get the latest (maximum) oid for a name and assign it to "newID" then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_newID() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
DECLARE maxid oid;
BEGIN
    IF new."newID" IS NOT NULL THEN
          RETURN new; -- do nothing
    END IF;
    SELECT max("ID") INTO maxid FROM tbl_ids WHERE "Name" = new."Name";
    new."newID" = maxid;
    RETURN new;
END;    
$$;
```

That works with oids and ints.  However it has to select a row from the db on each row modified by the trigger so you will have performance problems with bulk inserts for example.

Oh, and far better to use all lower case so you don't have to quote every identifier.

Comment: thx for the answer, I won't use oids any more :)
but like you said my problem seems not to be clear: I need a function like the COALESCE()-Function that works like  COALESCE(newID, ID): IF newID = NULL THEN use ID; IF newID !=NULL THEN use newID and COALESCE()-it again with the newID set as ID and the newID from the row;

Comment: Are you trying to traverse a tree?  Or a graph? In a trigger?  Why?

Comment: the first, but not as a trigger, but in a function similar to COALESCE().
I need to, because the ID's will never be able to bechanged it will end in an "historical groth" that will be neccecary. I'm not sure anymore if this will be a server-side function, i guess this will end in the middleware with a simple while-loop...

Comment: Just don't change id's and use a timestamp, and order that way.
The way you are doing things you will mostly give yourself headaches performance-wise.  RDBMS's work best on sets and recursion is a tool of last resort.